# How to count specific value from multiple column in another table and update the results

Tags: postgresql, count, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I have table1 as following

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 23 | 29 | 33 | 37 | 40 |
| 9 | 13 | 21 | 25 | 32 | 42 |
| 11 | 16 | 19 | 21 | 27 | 31 |
| 14 | 27 | 30 | 31 | 40 | 42 |
| 16 | 24 | 29 | 40 | 41 | 42 |
| 14 | 15 | 26 | 27 | 40 | 42 |
| 2 | 9 | 16 | 25 | 26 | 40 |
| 8 | 19 | 25 | 34 | 37 | 39 |
| 2 | 4 | 16 | 17 | 36 | 39 |
| 9 | 25 | 30 | 33 | 41 | 44 |
| 1 | 7 | 36 | 37 | 41 | 42 |
| 2 | 11 | 21 | 25 | 39 | 45 |
| 22 | 23 | 25 | 37 | 38 | 42 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 31 | 33 | 40 |
| 3 | 4 | 16 | 30 | 31 | 37 |

And table2 as following

| numbs | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 |  |
| 10 |  |
| 11 |  |
| 12 |  |
| 13 |  |
| 14 |  |
| 15 |  |
| 16 |  |
| 17 |  |
| 18 |  |
| 19 |  |
| 20 |  |

I would like to update **table2.result** buy counting total matched **numbs** value from **table1** column(a,b,c,d,e,f)

Have tried the below mentioned script but it's taking really long time to update fully so appreciate if somebody could provide me any alternative script which calculates faster.

```
UPDATE public.table2 AS t2 SET result = (select sum(
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN t2.numbs=t1.f THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )     
                FROM public.table1 AS t1 )
```

Comment: This is really a job for a programming language, where it would be easy.  SQL does not provide for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are no duplicate numbers in each row of `table1`(something like lottery numbers).

If my assumption is correct, you can simplify your code:

```
UPDATE table2 AS t2
SET result = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM table1 AS t1 
  WHERE t2.numbs IN (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b89a7abe3eeb88bb047b16c34030d3f).

Comment: In case there are dups, you can pivot columns to rows using jsonb functions.  Modification to your DB<>Fiddle here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25965f9e90e563beea6d6ca8f5c3dff5

Comment: @forpas it's working perfectly but still taking a lot of time to update 2mln rows of data, so is there any alternative script which calculates faster plz

Comment: @Mike Organek the following error is occurring; **ERROR:  cannot cast jsonb string to type integer
SQL state: 22023**  FYI plz, there are many other columns in table1 and maybe that's the reason thre is an error

Comment: @Gulya  Yes.  Extra columns would cause this problem.  You did not mention them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it can be done.  The fact that this is so ugly is an indication that your database is not properly designed.  If the numbers can be handled independently, then they should be in separate rows.

```
DROP TABLE numbers;
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    a int,
    b int,
    c int,
    d int,
    e int,
    f int
);

INSERT INTO numbers  VALUES
(10, 23, 29, 33, 37, 40),
(9, 13, 21, 25, 32, 42),
(11, 16, 19, 21, 27, 31),
(14, 27, 30, 31, 40, 42),
(16, 24, 29, 40, 41, 42),
(14, 15, 26, 27, 40, 42),
(2, 9, 16, 25, 26, 40),
(8, 19, 25, 34, 37, 39),
(2, 4, 16, 17, 36, 39),
(9, 25, 30, 33, 41, 44),
(1, 7, 36, 37, 41, 42),
(2, 11, 21, 25, 39, 45),
(22, 23, 25, 37, 38, 42),
(2, 6, 12, 31, 33, 40),
(3, 4, 16, 30, 31, 37)
;
DROP TABLE table2;
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    numbs int,
    result int
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0), 
(9,0), (10,0), (11,0), (12,0), (13,0), (14,0), (15,0),
(16,0), (17,0), (17,0), (18,0), (19,0), (20,0), (21,0),
(22,0), (23,0), (24,0);

UPDATE table2 SET result=0;


UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT a,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY a) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.a;
UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT b,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY b) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.b;
UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT c,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY c) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.c;
UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT d,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY d) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.d;
UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT e,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY e) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.e;
UPDATE table2 SET result = result + n.cnt
    FROM (SELECT f,count(*) cnt FROM numbers GROUP BY f) n
    WHERE table2.numbs = n.f;
```

Output:

```
sqlite> .mode box               
sqlite> select * from table2;   
┌───────┬────────┐              
│ numbs │ result │              
├───────┼────────┤              
│ 1     │ 1      │              
│ 2     │ 4      │              
│ 3     │ 1      │              
│ 4     │ 2      │              
│ 5     │ 0      │              
│ 6     │ 1      │              
│ 7     │ 1      │              
│ 8     │ 1      │              
│ 9     │ 3      │              
│ 10    │ 1      │              
│ 11    │ 2      │              
│ 12    │ 1      │              
│ 13    │ 1      │              
│ 14    │ 2      │              
│ 15    │ 1      │              
│ 16    │ 5      │              
│ 17    │ 1      │              
│ 17    │ 1      │              
│ 18    │ 0      │              
│ 19    │ 2      │              
│ 20    │ 0      │              
│ 21    │ 3      │              
│ 22    │ 1      │              
│ 23    │ 2      │              
│ 24    │ 1      │              
└───────┴────────┘              
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
update table2 
set result = (
  select sum(case when numbs in (a,b,c,d,e,f) then 1 else 0 end)
  from numbers
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=07ca7712820966087413c567e755cda9)*

Comment: the script is working perfectly super fast but the results for the entire 1.2mln rows of data is same results like 7 on the entire column

Comment: @Gulya , I can' tell what's happeneing on your side , but as you can see in fiddle , its working ok